# A subgroup of $\operatorname{sp}(4,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two matrices as follows:

$$ M_1= \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
 1 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
 5 &  5 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 &  -5 & -1 & 1\\
\end{array} \right)$$ and
 $$M_2= \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
 1 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 &  1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 &  0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array} \right). $$

One may easily check that
$$(M_1M_2)^5=I, $$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. A well known problem is the following:

Is the  relation $(M_1M_2)^5=I $, the only relation between $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Now my question is the following:

Does the group generated by $M_1$ and $M_2$ contain a free subgroup?

Is it known?

Comment: the subgroup generated by $M_2$ is certainly free; perhaps you'd like to refine the question

Comment: I think a group generated by an element is cyclic!

Comment: Yes, but I think user8268 is making the point that an infinite cyclic group is free of rank 1. Presumably your intention was to ask if there was a free subgroup of rank at least two. Have you heard of the Tits alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Since $$M_2^n=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & n \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

by induction on $n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$, we have that the subgroup $\langle M_2\rangle $ generated by $M_2$ is isomorphic to the free group $(\Bbb Z, +)\cong \langle m\mid \rangle$.